# Can cast button in android browser be configured cast to a custom receiver?

Tags: android, google-chrome, html5-video, chromecast, google-cast

Can the cast button in android chrome browser be configured to cast to a custom receiver?

Screenshot of the cast button that shows up in native android video controls:

[image: android mobile browser controls with cast button]

Comment: No. This is handled internally by the Chrome browser and cannot be customized.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: No. There is no API for developers for this feature in the mobile version of the Chrome browser.